# How to convert 'Styles' to 'Tags' <strong>, <em> when copy-paste from google docs TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-5

I'm new to TinyMCE. Our marketing team uses google docs to write descriptions which they copy and paste into our system which uses TinyMCE. I'm trying to convert all bold, italics and bullet styles into HTML tags ('strong' 'em' 'li') and strip out the rest of the inline stylings. Is there any way to do this?

This is the sample code:

````
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
   selector: "textarea",
   valid_children: 'p[strong|em|br|span],li[strong|em|br|span],div[strong|em|br|span|img]',
   menubar: false,
   plugins: [
         "print preview hr anchor pagebreak paste lists",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
   ],
  formats: {
    strong: { inline: 'span', element: 'strong' },
    em: { inline: 'span', element: 'em' }
  },
  toolbar: "undo redo | removeformat | bold italic bullist | print preview",
  height: "250"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>```
````

Comment: "TinyMCE" - ew - what year is it? 2007? Why not use Markdown like all the cool kids are doing instead?

Comment: "Is there any way to do this?" - no. there is not (at least, not robustly and _correctly_). This is one of the *many* reasons why people are moving away from `contenteditable`-based editors like TinyMCE.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the info. I will look into Markdown.